# Compilation issue while creating AOT angular 2 sample

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

Compilation issue while creating AOT angular 2 sample

While run command "npm run rollup -c rollup-config.js"

"can not resolve entry (app/main-aot.ts)"

Answer (score 0):

```
import rollup from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
//paths are relative to the execution path
export default {
entry: './app/main-aot.js',
dest: 'aot/dist/build.js', // output a single application bundle
sourceMap: true,
sourceMapFile: 'aot/dist/build.js.map',
format: 'iife',
plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
        jsnext: true,
        module: true
    }),
    commonjs({
        include: ['node_modules/rxjs/**']
    }),
    uglify()
]
```

}

My file is above